# How do I build a QBS Item that will facilitate and streamline the building and running of Qt's Web Assembly in QtCreator?

Tags: c++, qt, qmake, webassembly, qbs

Qt's WebAssembly relies on QMake.

I prefer QBS.

How do I build a QBS Item that will facilitate and streamline the building and running of Qt's Web Assembly in QtCreator?

Will I need to build a `.pro` file generator, and can this be done with a QBS item?

Comment: Great to hear that you prefer Qbs. There is unfortunately no out of the box support for Web Assembly in Qbs. But it would be fantastic to have. [Contributions](https://github.com/qbs/qbs/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) are welcome.